# Round float to closer (or closest one)

Tags: java, numbers, rounding

I have some "reference" float numbers (1.5, 3 and 7.1 for example), ***is there any way how to get some other "random" float rounded to closest one*** from the brackets?  (I mean if there's something like round, which can takes reference values for rounding)

Or is there any way how to get some number rounded to closer one from 2 (except manual decision of course) ?

I haven't found any method in Math, maybe some external lib? 
Or is better idea to write own method for that (get absolute difference to every value from bracket and get smallest one)?
It's banality I know, but it could be useful..

Thanks for any response

edit- 
eg.:
If I want to

- "round" 1, get 1.5
- round 5, get 3
- round 8, get 7.7
- round 1.7, get 1.5

etc.

Comment: Can you put some example of what you mean ?? It will be easy for us to understand ..

Comment: So you want to "round" `2.24 to 1.5`, `2.26 to 3`, `5.04 to 3` and `5.06 to 7.1`? If so the normal rules of rounding wont apply (e.g. round down up to but not included .5, round up after .5) and you have to make your own rule.

Comment: No, no, I mean eg. 
Number "to round"- 1.8 - so get closest one from the bracket- so in this case 1.5, number to round - 5.2 - get 7.1, 
3 get 3, 4 get 3, etc.

Comment: Hah, there will be problem in this case eg. if I want to round 2, because there's difference 0.5 to 3 and also to 1.5 x), but just for example :)

sorry, hinneLinks, your example looks great :)

Comment: You don't need to get the difference to every value: if your array of reference numbers is sorted, you can just do a binary search for your result, and the two neighbours are the ones you need to check the distance of. Every other element is bound to be even further.

Comment: Nice idea :) Thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more optimum answers:

the **"for i"** way, easier to read

```
private static double roundForI(double toRound, double[] numbers) {
    int minIndex = 0;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double diff;
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; ++i) {
        diff = Math.abs(numbers[i]-toRound);
        if (diff < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diff;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return numbers[minIndex];
}
```

a shorter one, the **"For each"** way

```
private static double roundForEach(double toRound, double[] numbers) {
    double diff, roundValue = 0, minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (double dob : numbers) {
        if ((diff = Math.abs(dob-toRound)) < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diff;
            roundValue = dob;
        }
    }
    return roundValue;
}
```

and the **"Java8 Golf Style"** way, which it's not better way than the 2 above.

```
private static double roundLambda(double n, double[] a) {
    double[] r = {0}, d = {Double.MAX_VALUE};
    Arrays.stream(a).filter((i)->Math.abs(i-n)<d[0]).forEach(i->{d[0]=Math.abs(i-n);r[0]=i;});
    return r[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should roughly do what you want:

```
private static double round(double toRound, double[] numbers) {
    double diff = Math.abs(numbers[0]-toRound);
    double ret = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(numbers[i] - toRound) < diff) {
            diff = Math.abs(numbers[i] - toRound);
            ret = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

but please remark that when the difference of the number to round to 2 of the roundable numbers is the same, it will return the number which comes first in the array!